# R seq function too many arguments?

Tags: r, sequence

I am getting an error that I don't really understand at all.  I was just messing around with generating some sequences, and I came across this problem:

This should create a sequence of 50 numbers.

```
seq.int(from=1,to=1000,by=5,length.out=50)
```

But if I enter this in the console I get the error message:

> Error in seq.int(from = 1, to = 1000, by = 5, length.out = 50) :
>   too many arguments

If I look at the help (`?seq`), in the Usage section  there is this line in there which makes it seem as though I called the function correctly, and it allows this many number of arguments:

> seq.int(from, to, by, length.out, along.with, ...)

So what the heck is going on?  I am I missing something fundamental, or are the docs out of date?

**NOTE**
The arguments I am providing to the function in the code sample are just for sake of example.  I'm not trying to solve a particular problem, just curious as to why I get the error.

Comment: this makes perfect sense, because either you're being redundant by specifying both, or you're giving conflicting information--i.e., each implies the other.

Comment: @MichaelChirico I don't think it makes perfect sense though. I can picture a scenario in my mind when you don't know apriori the `from` and `to` arguments and pass it within some function (or a function receives them from a user) and you always want the sequence by `5` and stop after 50 results. In this case when reaching 246. I think this makes perfect sense, no to mention it isn't really documented. Of course you can do it as in that "answer" below, but it is inefficient because you are calculating the whole vector first.

Comment: @MichaelChirico I agree with David, it doesn't make perfect sense, and it isn't redundant.  I may know from, to and by, but not length for example.  Yes, I can compute it all myself, but doesn't that kind of defeat the purpose of having a function like this?

Comment: @DavidArenburg: In the case you propose as needing the tow arguments, wouldn't using `seq`'s 'along.with' argument instead of either one of 'by', or 'length.out' provide the better solution?

Comment: gotcha, missed that you're stopping well short of 1000. a problem remains--how is `seq.int` supposed to know you mean "start from `to`, go by `by`, stop when `length.out` elements are produced"` instead of any number of other interpretations--e.g., "end at `from`, decrease by `by` until `length.out` elements are produced"??

Comment: Also, `seq.int(from=1,by=5,length.out=50)` doesn't suffice?

Comment: @BondedDust can't think of a good example with `along.with` but it seems like Micahel is up to something.

Comment: @MichaelChirico yeah I agree that `to` and and `length.out` have some contradiction here. I think illustrating that contradiction along with your proposed solution could be a goo answer.

Comment: @MichaelChirico The actual arguments in the question are just a contrived example.  The spirit of the question is why does calling the function with these arguments pitch a fit when the documentation seems to indicate otherwise.

Comment: it is interesting because there are so many ways that the sequence can be made.  You can look at the relevant source, https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/seq.c#L707, at line 707, and your error is the last `else` statement

Comment: if the `to` argument is missing, it will set the `to` value to be: `to = from + (length.out-1)*by`.  One of `by`, `to`, or `from` must be missing to do a sequence as you are.

Comment: @A.R. When you specify `to`, `by` and `length.out`, how the function supposed to decide what to do when there is a contradiction between `to` and `length.out`? In your case, the result should be a vector of length `50` with it's last value equals `246`, but `to` tells the function it should be `1000`. What should it do? Unless you set some precedence rules.

Comment: @David Arenburg It isn't a contradiction at all.  Read the docs again.  lenngth.out says "desired length...", which doesn't mean that is the length you are going to get, so if there aren't enough numbers then the list is truncated.  Furthermore, the description for 'from,to' states: "(maximal) end value..." meaning that this is the highest 'possible' value NOT the highest value.  Based on these definitions, I would expect to get a sequence that goes from->to->by, up to length.out elements.

Comment: Though you are correct regarding `to`, `length.out` is *exactly* the length you going to get. Try, a simple example such as `length(seq(1, 3, length.out = 10))`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, there is nothing fundamental to the R language that I was missing that was the source of the problem.  The problem is that the documents, at least at time of writing, are misleading and/or incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear what you expect as output from this line of code, and you're getting an error because `R` doesn't want to resolve the contradictions *for you*.

Here is some valid output, and the line of code you'd use to achieve each. This is a case where you need to decide for yourself which approach to use given the task you have in mind:

## Override `length.out`

```
  [1]   1   6  11  16  21  26  31  36  41  46  51  56  61  66  71  76  81  86
  ...
[199] 991 996

#via:
seq.int(from=1,to=1000,by=5)
```

## Override `by`

```
 [1]    1.00000   21.38776   41.77551   62.16327   82.55102  102.93878  123.32653
 [8]  143.71429  164.10204  184.48980  204.87755  225.26531  245.65306  266.04082
[15]  286.42857  306.81633  327.20408  347.59184  367.97959  388.36735  408.75510
[22]  429.14286  449.53061  469.91837  490.30612  510.69388  531.08163  551.46939
[29]  571.85714  592.24490  612.63265  633.02041  653.40816  673.79592  694.18367
[36]  714.57143  734.95918  755.34694  775.73469  796.12245  816.51020  836.89796
[43]  857.28571  877.67347  898.06122  918.44898  938.83673  959.22449  979.61224
[50] 1000.00000

#via:
seq.int(from=1,to=1000,length.out=50)
```

## Override `to`

```
 [1]   1   6  11  16  21  26  31  36  41  46  51  56  61  66  71  76  81  86  91  96 101
[22] 106 111 116 121 126 131 136 141 146 151 156 161 166 171 176 181 186 191 196 201 206
[43] 211 216 221 226 231 236 241 246

#via:
seq.int(from=1,by=5,length.out=50)
```

## Override `from`

```
 [1]  755  760  765  770  775  780  785  790  795  800  805  810  815  820  825  830  835  840
[19]  845  850  855  860  865  870  875  880  885  890  895  900  905  910  915  920  925  930
[37]  935  940  945  950  955  960  965  970  975  980  985  990  995 1000

#via:
seq.int(to=1000,by=5,length.out=50)
```

*A priori*, `R` has no way of telling which of the above you'd like, nor should it. You as programmer need to decide which inputs take precedence.

And you're right that this should be documented; for now, take a look at the [source of `.Primitive("seq.int")`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/seq.c#L707), as linked originally by @nongkrong.

Comment: Feel free to suggest revisions on `r-devel@r-project.org` ... (not just "someone should fix this", but "here are some revisions I made to the existing man page, in the form of diffs from the current SVN version" ... Richie Cotton has had some success recently in submitting documentation improvements)

Comment: But how can we do it in `dplyr`?

Comment: My question has nothing to do with this at all.  I know how to generate sequences in many different ways, and I even mention that the arguments I provided are for the sake of example and not to solve any particular problem.  The correct answer is that the documentation is incorrect/unclear.

Comment: @A.R. if you look at the linked source, you'll see that function decides how to make the sequence by checking to see which argument is missing.  If none are missing, then it throws that error that you are seeing.

Comment: @MichaelChirico: The stated question is: "I am I missing something fundamental, or are the docs out of date?"  I did the research, using the documents.  They are incorrect / out of date / misleading.  Your "answer", contains a lot of helpful information, but doesn't address the question.

Comment: @nongkrong Yep, I see that.  I usually like to rely on the docs so that I don't have to read source code, but I am finding with R that the docs are kind of meh quality.  I guess I will just read the source from now on, thanks!